Configuring Jetty 9 REST service for CORS header working in Chrome
I have been searching for CORS examples with Jetty 9 embedded, and haven't had any success.
My Jetty 9 REST Service as backend for SQLite works fine in Postman but not in the Browser.
How can I create, configure and register a resource with a CORSFilter class to work in Chrome browser:
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    Server jettyServer = new Server(8889);     
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);
     
    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");
    
    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
    
    // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(
        "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",
        PersonResource.class.getCanonicalName());

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        // jettyServer.dump(System.err); // --- ??? --- Handlings? ---
        jettyServer.join();
    } finally {
        jettyServer.destroy();
    }

